# Navigation bar disappears when typing in UISearchController text field

Tags: uitableview, ios8, uinavigationbar, uisearchcontroller

I'm trying to figure out why my whole navigation bar disappears when I start typing in the UISearchController.searchBar  It loads properly and animates properly, but I lose the active NavBar when I start typing.  Here's the code to load the searchController from viewDidLoad:

```
    UITableViewController *searchResultsController = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

    searchResultsController.tableView.dataSource = self;
    searchResultsController.tableView.delegate = self;
    searchResultsController.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];    

    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:searchResultsController];
    self.searchController.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = YES;
    self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;

    [self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
    self.definesPresentationContext = NO;
```

And here's the result after I start typing:

[image]

Notice how the table view is there, but it appears to occupy the space of the nav controller and extend downwards into the first section heading.  Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: posted solution below, but I'm not sure exactly where the problem was yet. =]

Comment: np, thanks, I'll take a look at that

Answer (score 8):

You need to set definesPresentationContext to YES. From apples example:

```
// Search is now just presenting a view controller. As such, normal view controller
// presentation semantics apply. Namely that presentation will walk up the view controller
// hierarchy until it finds the root view controller or one that defines a presentation context.

self.definesPresentationContext = YES
```

Comment: But it also says, "Some system-provided view controllers, such as UINavigationController, change the default value to true." So if it's embedded in a navigation controller, why would it still disappear?

Answer (score 0):

this work for me

`self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = true;`

Answer (score 0):

So, I was eventually able to solve this problem with this following init sequence.  However, I'm not too sure what I did to make this happen.  Kind of busy right now, so I'll just paste this solution and will accept a solution if somebody can pinpoint.

```
- (void)loadSearchBar
{

    NSLog(@"Loading SearchBar");

    UITableViewController *searchResultsController = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    UITableView *myTv = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    searchResultsController.tableView = myTv;
    searchResultsController.tableView.dataSource = self;
    searchResultsController.tableView.delegate = self;
    searchResultsController.tableView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag;
    searchResultsController.tableView.sectionIndexColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:linkBlue];

    self.searchResultsController = searchResultsController;

    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:searchResultsController];
    self.searchController.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = YES;
    self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
    self.searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.x, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.y, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.size.width, 44.0);

    self.searchBar = self.searchController.searchBar;
    self.searchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    self.searchBar.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
    self.searchBar.delegate = self;
    self.searchBar.translucent = YES;
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView.layer.zPosition++;

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;

    //add color to search field
    UIView *subviews = [self.searchBar.subviews lastObject];
    UITextField *textView = (id)[subviews.subviews objectAtIndex:1];

    textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:textFieldBlue];

}
```