# The navigation bar disappears in the search result table view

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchcontroller

I am trying to have a UISearchController in the navigation bar and display the results in an external controller.

For some reason the navigation bar disappear as soon as I type something in

I have been trying different solutions for a few hours with no results. It looks like it is a similar issue as [Navigation bar disappears when typing in UISearchController text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26637215/navigation-bar-disappears-when-typing-in-uisearchcontroller-text-field) and 
[Navigation bar disappears if reload data with UISearchController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27098127/navigation-bar-disappears-if-reload-data-with-uisearchcontroller) that did not get any answer.

```
self.cearchController = ({
        //creating another tableview
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
        let alternateController:SearchResultsTableViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SearchResultsTableViewController") as! SearchResultsTableViewController
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: alternateController)
        controller.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = alternateController
        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        controller.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"

        self.navigationItem.titleView = controller.searchBar


        return controller
    })()
```

I have tried 
     `self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)`

and I have
    `myResultsTableView.definesPresentationContext = true`

in the viewdidload

this is what it looks like :
[image: <>]

**Note**: I have only started with swift a few days ago so I might be missing something really obvious!!

Thanks and happy to add more code

Comment: you could check whether it's when the keyboard appears? use this: navigationController?.hidesBarsWhenKeyboardAppears = false // also, check this link http://natashatherobot.com/navigation-bar-interactions-ios8/

Comment: Did you find the solution to the problem? I am facing similar issue and can not find the root cause of it.

Answer (score 2):

So I had a similar issue of the navbar disappearing when my search results were shown. But controller.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false did the trick for me.

Maybe try using tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar instead of self.navigationItem.titleView = controller.searchBar